# batch download of all datasets on a socrata site

Tags: socrata

Is there a way for me to schedule a one time batch job of the 'About data set' for all 392 data sets on 'https://data.cityofboston.gov/'?

I'm not interested in downloading the data, just the info box which gives name of data set, date published, author, etc (see screenshot below).  Is there any automated/batch way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for the metadata for all of the datasets on that domain. The simplest way to do so is to grab the `data.json` feed of that domain's catalog, like this:

https://data.cityofboston.gov/data.json